# Forgot to mention subject in my letter, what should I do?

Tags: email, mistakes

I forgot to specify subject for my letter. I already apply macros for my Outlook so I will not do this again. Is there something I should do for this sent email?

Comment: Depends on the content. In most cases, sending it again with the correct subject is sufficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens.  People might be a little confused, but you shouldn't need to resend the email unless the subject line contants important information that you didn't include in the email.

If you don't get a response in a reasonable timescale, you can try resending with the correct subject line.